# Setting tcolorbox border width

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying tcolorbox for the first time and want to create a tcolorbox environment that has thick red borders.

This was my attempt:

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{titleEnv}{center,
width=0.75\linewidth,
opacityback=0,
standard jigsaw,
halign=center,
borderline west={1mm}{0mm}{red},
borderline east={3mm}{0mm}{red},
borderline south={3mm}{0mm}{red},
borderline north={1mm}{0mm}{red}
}
```

It makes a nice transparent box, but the border lines are thin and black.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should be closer to the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{titleEnv}{
center,
width=0.75\linewidth,
halign=center,
colframe=red,
colback=white
}


\begin{document}

\begin{titleEnv}
some contents
\end{titleEnv}

\end{document}
```

---

Update regarding different border widths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{titleEnv}{
center,
width=0.75\linewidth,
halign=center,
colframe=red,
colback=white, 
boxrule=1pt,
rightrule=3pt,
bottomrule=3pt
}


\begin{document}

\begin{titleEnv}
some contents
\end{titleEnv}

\end{document}
```

---

The thicker border on the bottom and left side of the box reminded me of a drop shadow, so here is such a version as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{titleEnv}{
 enhanced jigsaw,
center,
width=0.75\linewidth,
halign=center,
colframe=red,
colback=white, 
boxrule=1pt,
drop shadow=red,%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{titleEnv}
some contents
\end{titleEnv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, but it doesn't give control of the border line width.

Comment: @user1683586: I have just updated my answer to reflect on that as well.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @leandris I have run the code of your third illustration, but I get two errors: ``I do not know the key `tcb/center' and I am going to ignore it." Similarly, for the key `tcb/halign'.  Consequently, the text ``some contents'' is not centered for me. Is there something I can do to correct this problem on my end? Thank you.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch: Which version of `tcolorbox`  do you have? `halign` seems to have been introduced in version 3.60 ([from 2015](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.484.1431106682.4386.ctan-ann@dante.de)), so updating to a more recent version should fix this issue.

Comment: @leandris Texstudio 2.6.6 I believe. Do you think that would be the reason I cannot produce many of the centered title boxes from the tcolorbox manual? Thanks again,

Comment: The version of Texstudio is not related with the `tcolorbox` version you are using. Most likely an outdated installation also causes the other issues you mention. Since `halign` is undefined, your tcolorbox version (and most likely other packages as well) must be more than 5 years old. If you don't explicitly need such an old installation for some reason, updating will most likely not hurt, especially since a lot of packages also received bug fixes and feature updates.

Comment: @leandris Thank you again.