# How can I add a header image to my shadowbox?

Tags: positioning, box

I have a somewhat strange scenario in which I am required to create the following entity:

[image]

where the red box indicates a small picture in the form of a PNG file.

I already know how to create the shadowed box with the text:

```
\shadowbox{
    \begin{minipage}{310pt}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    \end{minipage}
}
```

[image]

but I have no clue how to add a picture to the top left corner. I have tried `\includegraphics` but the included picture always remains within the `\shadowbox`, whereas I would want it half-in, half-out.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can consider to use the `tcolorbox` package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527248/ for an example that is similar to your use case. That one is for theorems, but you can also use it for regular text, and instead of a textual title you can also use an `\includegraphics` command in the title.

Comment: And for an example of drop shadow with `tcolorbox` you could look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567623/setting-tcolorbox-border-width/.